# Callback to a dynamic value in GameObject.transform

Tags: unity, movement, input, quaternion

I'm currently writing an `InputManager` using Unity's "new" input system.  The `InputManager` receives all player input via `SendMessage()` and disseminates it to the appropriate objects (player, UI, et cetera).  In an attempt to adhere to SRP (single-responsibility principle), I want as much of the message massaging to occur in the `InputManager` as possible.

For player movement in the `InputManager`, I have the following:

```
public void OnMovement(InputValue input)
{
    if (playerControl == null)
        playerControl = player.GetComponent<PlayerControl>();

    playerControl.OnMovement(input, playerMovementSpeed, cmCam.gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles);
}
```

on the `PlayerControl` script, I have:

```
void Update()
{
    var q = Quaternion.Euler(cmCam.transform.localEulerAngles);
    q.x = 0;
    this.gameObject.transform.localPosition += q * moveVec * Time.deltaTime * playerMovementSpeed;
}

public void OnMovement(InputValue input, float speed, Vector3 cameraRotationAngle)
{
    playerMovementSpeed = speed;

    Vector2 inputVec = input.Get<Vector2>();

    // Must multiply quat * vec | vec * quat causes an exception
    //moveVec = Quaternion.Euler(cameraRotationAngle) * new Vector3(inputVec.x, 0, inputVec.y);
    moveVec = new Vector3(inputVec.x, 0, inputVec.y);
}
```

I'm using the `Quaternion` of the `CinemachineCamera` so that as the camera rotates, directional movement accounts for it without having to stop and restart movement.  At the same time, because it's a pseudo-isometric view, I want the `x-value` of the camera to be ignored (otherwise forward/backward movement has a skipping to it).

The current code **works** as-is, but querying and modifying the camera's returned `transform` value every frame via update seems less than ideal.  I can't measure the performance impact because I can't figure out another way to do it.

Is there a way to make some sort of callback value that will give me `Quaternion(w, 0, y, z)' of that camera's transform every frame?

Ignore the `cameraRotationAngle` in the signature of `playerControl.OnMovement` - that was part of my initial attempt, but the value isn't updated until movement stops and restarts, so that will likely be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> modifying the cameras transform every frame via update seems less than ideal.

Then I have good news for you: you're not doing that. The code you've shown does not modify the camera's transform component in any way shape or form.

> Is there a way to make some sort of callback value that will give me `Quaternion(0, y, z, w)' of that camera's transform every frame?

First, that is *not* what you want. Zeroing out the x component of a quaternion is not a way to remove the pitch component of the rotation.  Instead, this can add a twisting roll to the camera.

Here's a gif that demonstrates this. On the left is the source object for the rotation, which I show pitching down then yawing through a full 360 degrees. On the right there's are two copies of the object, in blue and red. The blue copy is using the correct flattening code I show below. The red copy is just setting `quaternion.x = 0`. You can see that while they're equivalent at `yaw = 0`, as we rotate around the y, the red copy develops a rolling twist - deviating more than 6 degrees from level, as shown in the transform properties on the right. This error can grow much larger if the source pitch is greater.

[image: Demo gif]

It looks like what you want is a camera-relative flattening method, as shown here:

[Camera relative movement is pushing into/off the ground instead of parallel](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/125945/39518)

If you'd like to make the syntax look like a member method call, you can do that with an extension method:

```
public static class TransformExtensions {
    public static Quaternion GetPlanarRotation(this Transform transform, Vector3 planeNormal = default) {
        if (planeNormal == default) planeNormal = Vector3.up;

        return Quaternion.LookRotation(planeNormal, -transform.forward) * Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Then you can just say...

```
var q = cmCam.transform.GetPlanarRotation();
transform.localPosition += q * moveVec * Time.deltaTime * playerMovementSpeed;
```

Comment: as always, thank you.  Just a note, I didn't mean modifying the camera's transform object, but taking the camera's transform value and modifying that returned value {get} to use for the calculation.

Comment: If you want something that's not stored, then it's pretty natural that you'll need to do a computation to get it, no?

Comment: Yes, definitely a typical method - I was mostly just interested to see if such a thing could be done.  As an aside, for a free-floating camera, I'd agree that zeroing out one of the Vector components of a Quaternion would be... bad. In this instance, only yaw and pitch can actually change, and the localized Vector of movement is "static" for lack of a better word (from the perspective of the camera).  Manual manipulation of Quaternions is rightly frowned upon, but in this instance it's a good tool.  The GetPlanarRotation() method costs DOUBLE the processor time - a whopping extra 0.004ms LOL.

Comment: That last bit was tongue-in-cheek, FWIW.

Comment: Even when using only yaw and pitch as inputs, you can get roll out when using the method that you're showing. I can add a gif later to demonstrate.

Comment: please do.  I stepped through a few matrices of variations on how the resulting values should look setting x=0 and didn't find one that would cause roll, but it was far from comprehensive.  If I can learn something new about quaternion math, I surely wouldn't complain!

Comment: Updated with an example. I showed a relatively mild case here, but the error can easily exceed 20 degrees if your input pitch is steeper.

Comment: Interesting - thank you! I’m going to have to run my matrices again. It always helps me to actually understand the why of the thing lol. But yes, I can definitely see how that appears problematic. Now I’m wondering what prevents me seeing this effect in the game - possibly something to do with how the CinemachineCamera object works, but better to use the right logic than just any ol’ working logic. As it is now I can turn about the y-axis indefinitely with no I’ll effects, so there must be something preventing the roll. Must figure out what… lol